# Can't deploy an application twice using Glassfish Embedded v3.1

Tags: junit, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

I'm having trouble with the following scenario:

> - Start JVM.
> - Start GlassFish Embedded v3.1.
> - Deploy my application EAR.
> - Undeploy my application.
> - Restart GlassFish Embedded v3.1, i.e., stop and start.
> - Deploy my application EAR. -- crashes

I've tried without restarting glassfish embedded, i.e., just with undeploy and deploy commands and it still crashes.

The goal is to automate some end-product testing. Involving glassfish lifecycle and configuration.

Looking at the active Threads I see that even after calling `GlassFish.stop()` or `GlassFish.dispose()`, there are still Daemon Threads that won't go away before JVM shuts down.

Starting glassfish again goes ok, but on the second deploy I get address already in use when it tries to start EJBContainer, it might be some of these Daemon Threads that are holding it...

I've search a lot, almost every tutorial and/or documentation about GlassFish embedded uses it with Maven and with a single server instance thru JVM life-time.

Is there a way I can redeploy an application on GlassFish v3.1 embedded?

Restarting GlassFish embedded instance before trying the second deploy I get this stacktrace and the JVM get stuck:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:821)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:155)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.<init>(StatelessSessionContainer.java:149)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:249)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:97)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoServidorAplicacao.deploy(ServicoServidorAplicacao.java:119)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoCsmCenter.iniciar(ServicoCsmCenter.java:34)
    at asdioha.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getProtocolManager(GlassFishORBHelper.java:187)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:818)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.omg.CORBA.OBJ_ADAPTER: WARNING: IOP02310002: Error in connecting servant to ORB  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 2  completed: No
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:622)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:120)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.OBJ_ADAPTER: WARNING: IOP02310002: Error in connecting servant to ORB  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 2  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy145.orbConnectError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.connect(ORBImpl.java:1698)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.connect(StubAdapter.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getIOR(ORBImpl.java:2088)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getFVDCodeBaseIOR(ORBImpl.java:988)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.addServiceContexts(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:802)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:61)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:61)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:61)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1266)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:586)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: SEVERE: IOP00410016: Unable to create IIOP listener on the specified host all interfaces and port 3,700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 16  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy145.createListenerFailed(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:98)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:262)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:103)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAImpl.<init>(TOAImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAFactory.getTOA(TOAFactory.java:118)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.connect(ORBImpl.java:1696)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createServerSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:293)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:91)
    ... 47 more
```

By the way, if I do not restart GlassFish, the deploy works the second time and fails on third:

```
17/03/2011 08:07:07 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:97)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoServidorAplicacao.deploy(ServicoServidorAplicacao.java:119)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoCsmCenter.iniciar(ServicoCsmCenter.java:34)
    at asdioha.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:234)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(WebModuleContextConfig.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5268)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2798)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadListener(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadListener(WebModule.java:1603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2685)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createListenerInstance(WebContainer.java:734)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createListenerInstance(WebModule.java:1981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.createListener(StandardContext.java:2796)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener/timerAccessEvent,Remote 3.x interface =com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier resolved to intra-app EJB AccessEventVerifier in module csm-center-ejb.jar,ejb-link=csm-center-ejb.jar#AccessEventVerifier,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier,refType=Session into class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:698)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:146)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:311)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener/timerAccessEvent' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener/timerAccessEvent,Remote 3.x interface =com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier resolved to intra-app EJB AccessEventVerifier in module csm-center-ejb.jar,ejb-link=csm-center-ejb.jar#AccessEventVerifier,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier#com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier#com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch]]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:597)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener/timerAccessEvent,Remote 3.x interface =com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier resolved to intra-app EJB AccessEventVerifier in module csm-center-ejb.jar,ejb-link=csm-center-ejb.jar#AccessEventVerifier,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier#com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier#com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch]]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1097)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:772)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:740)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier#com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:173)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacecom.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.event.IAccessEventVerifier [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch]
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:434)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:75)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.createRemoteBusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:657)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:427)
    ... 56 more
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start
WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:97)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoServidorAplicacao.deploy(ServicoServidorAplicacao.java:119)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoCsmCenter.iniciar(ServicoCsmCenter.java:34)
    at asdioha.Main.main(Main.java:22)
17/03/2011 08:07:07 org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo start
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:97)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoServidorAplicacao.deploy(ServicoServidorAplicacao.java:119)
    at com.senior.testes.automacao.junit.minilang.servico.ServicoCsmCenter.iniciar(ServicoCsmCenter.java:34)
    at asdioha.Main.main(Main.java:22)
17/03/2011 08:07:07 org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer cleanupResources
WARNING: [MDBContainer] Current thread done cleanup()... 
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer cleanupResources
WARNING: [MDBContainer] Current thread done cleanup()... 
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase closeMOM
INFO: Closing Metro monitoring root: amx:pp=/mon/server-mon[server],type=WSEndpoint,name=CsmCenterAdmService-CsmCenterAdmPort
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer cleanupResources
WARNING: [MDBContainer] Current thread done cleanup()... 
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer cleanupResources
WARNING: [MDBContainer] Current thread done cleanup()... 
classLoader = WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@1e3c4ea4
classLoader = WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@1e3c4ea4
17/03/2011 08:07:07 com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService _destroyTimers
INFO: No timers to be deleted for id: 85220387655778304
17/03/2011 08:07:07 org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand execute
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener
PlainTextActionReporterFAILUREDescription: deploy AdminCommandError occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class com.senior.seguranca.csmcenter.CsmCenterContextListener. Please see server.log for more details.
    [name=csm-center-glassfish
```

Thanks,
Thiago Negri.

Comment: At our company we also struggle with Glassfish, seems that 3.1 is not for production, simply not that quality. Even not stable enough to use as a sandbox. Repeating the same deploy cycle seems undeterministic. My condolances..